# How to import csv file with double quotes in a string from S3 to Redshift using copy command?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, etl

I am trying to import a file in csv format from S3 into Redshift. The fail from stl_load_errors is
**Invalid quote formatting for CSV** . Unfortunately I can't handle the source it comes from, so I am trying to figure it out only with the option from copy command.

Example file:
1;2;3;"Hello world "people""

Current copy command:
COPY xxxx
FROM 'S3_BCT'
credentials 'xxxxxx'
CSV EMPTYASNULL TIMEFORMAT AS 'auto'
DELIMITER ';'
TRUNCATECOLUMNS;

I tried using the QUOTE '"' solution but didn't work. Same with REMOVEQUOTES.

Thank you in advance guys!!

Answer (score 1):

True CSV (vs. just having commas in a text file) has a specification.  See: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180

Redshift follows this specification when the CSV option is added to the COPY command.  Rule 7 covers this case:

> If double-quotes are used to enclose fields, then a double-quote
> appearing inside a field must be escaped by preceding it with
> another double quote.  For example:
>
> ```
>    "aaa","b""bb","ccc"
> ```